# How do I get the 2nd block to play after the first?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm using PyAutoGUI to control the keyboard, followed by the mouse. I'm trying to get the 2nd block to play after the previous one:

```
for _ in range(repetitions):
    pyautogui.keyDown('tab')
    pyautogui.keyUp('tab')
    word = random.choice(word_list)
    pyautogui.typewrite(f"{word}")
    time.sleep(0.1)

pyautogui.moveTo(980, 777)
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.click()
```

Comment: Well, your `moveTo()` block should be running after your loop runs out of `repetitions`. What happens instead?